# Is the close vote review limit and close vote limit different?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-close

At my [close vote review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) it says

> Thank you for reviewing 40 close votes today; come back in 4 hours to
>   continue reviewing.

While I can vote to close more. It says I have 9 votes remaining.

Does it mean the close vote review limit and the close vote limit are different?

Comment: Since you're seeing two different things, isn't the answer to this vacuously "yes"? Do you have a deeper question you wanted answered?

Comment: Yes, the limit is different. Unless a review queue is over a certain threshold (I think 1000 reviews in the queue) the limit of reviews you can do is 20. If the queue has more reviews available than the threshold, you get 40 reviews. Close votes are different.

Comment: oh It was so simple,I thought it may be same like `Suggested Edits` where I review 20 edits I cannot edit more. That's why I asked.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam You can still edit posts even if you're out of reviews in the suggested edit review queue.  You just can't approve or reject suggested edits anymore.

Comment: Here is the [rate-limit guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/158100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean the close vote review limit and the close vote limit are different?

Yes.

Comment: [Well put](http://marv4mobeats.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/less-is-more-signs.jpg) :P